# Good way to append two integers into another integer in TSQL statement?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

We're using SQL Server 2005 and wanted to append two integers into another one.  Right now we're summing the month and year of a date field, which isn't really what we want.  Instead, we'd like to append them together, but retain an integer.

Here's what we have right now:

```
SELECT 
       YEAR( MeetingDate) + MONTH( MeetingDate) AS DateGroup
```

We'd like DateGroup to read 20118, 20119, 201110, 201111 etc.  Trying to learn some good ways of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a leading zero for one digit months, i.e. 201108 rather than 20118, then it's easy:

```
select
   year(MeetingDate) * 100 + month(MeetingDate) as DateGroup
```

Otherwise you have to treat some months differently:

```
select
   year(MeetingDate) * case when month(MeetingDate) < 10 then 10 else 100 end
   + month(MeetingDate) as DateGroup
```

Answer (score 2):

Cast your integers to varchar and then add them togehter.

```
select cast(cast(year(MeetingDate) as varchar(4)) + 
            cast(month(MeetingDate) as varchar(2)) as int) as dategroup
```

Comment: That returns a varchar, not an int.

Comment: @Guffa - I missed that part of the question. Concentrated more on the issue of removing the `0` from the month. Updated answer but I really think that he would do best to keep the `0` in the value.